# Getting Folder Properties Dialog Box To Properly Display Folder Filecount Contents and Foldersize

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

Please take a look at a couple of screenshots.

folder properties dialog box for folder on c:-drive:

[image]

folder properties dialog box for folder on f:-external drive:

[image]

The first screenshot is the PROPERTIES-dialog for a folder (which is accessed via clicking through my desktop) on my computer, on my c:-drive.
As you can see, while the PROPERTIES-dialog for the folder shows "0 files and 0bytes" for the folder, this simply isn't so; there are files in it and they have file sizes, too.

The second screenshot is the PROPERTIES-dialog for a COPY of the exact folder that is on my F:-external drive, replete with proper file-count and file sizes.

As it so happens, **I DO know why this is**.

It has NOTHING to do with such things as hidden files, incidentally).

The fullpaths for the files (i.e., the root directory + all the relevant subdirectories + the filename itself) are very long. Once a file's filename -- or a file's fullpath, rather -- reaches a certain number of characters, the file simply won't be reflected in the PROPERTIES-dialog.

This is a bit of a problem.

I am trying to transfer files from a directory deep on the desktop of my C:-drive, onto a new folder on my F:-external drive.

While I think I may have found software that'll allow me to copy over folders and files with very long fullpaths, since I'll be purging the data from my C:-drive in time, I would like to have the peace of mind that the contents of the original folder and the destination folder are identical.

I'd be very appreciative of any help.

Comment: Try `subst z: c:\some\very\long\path\name` and see if properties on `z:` give the right answer.

Comment: I took out the paragraph asking for a software recommendation so this won't get closed as off topic